# UDDI add custom category

Tags: uddi

In UDDI services when I click on "Add custom category" in order to add custom category to my tModel, I see a search box appears and "Add Category" button is disabled.

How can i add custom categories to my tModel??

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of an implementation specific answer.

The UDDI spec does not explicitly require data integrity on referenced tModels (i.e. if I use uddi:my.tmodel.key attached to a businessService/categogyBag/keyedreference, then the tModel uddi:my.tmodel.key must be defined already).

Using jUDDI 3.2, this requirement is turned on by default, however it can be disabled in the config.

Long short short, you should create a tModel with the key uddi:my.tmodel.key (or whatever), then reference that in your new tModel.

Quick update. Since you didn't mention what user interface you're looking at or what product you're using, it's difficult for me to tell why the button is grayed out. There's at least four different implementations of UDDI. Perhaps you're not signed in, or there's no tModels defined. I'd suggest contact the author's of the product you're using.